# Bootstrap Columns Order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I have footer section on the website I'm currently building, and the problem is order of them showing. I want to social icons be above ©

Have a look: [footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HURuk.png)

html:

```
<div id="footerbot">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5 class="fbh">&copy;2018 - Appo, All Right Reserved</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"  href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"  href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/dribble.png" href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/gplus.png" href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/youtube.png" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
</div>
```

css:

```
#footerbot {
background-color: rgba(34, 48, 71, 0.8);
}
#footerbot img {
display: block;
float: right;
top: 50%;
padding-top: 35px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
#footerbot h5 {
color: #00FFF0;
line-height: 100px;
}
```

I tried to add class 'order-md-6' to each div with col-md-6, but first of all it didn't work, and secondly it broke layout - it 'pushed' both elements to center. Is it even possible in bootstrap4? I also have a problem centering these items u can see on image I've upload. I'm struggling with this for 2hours and I have no idea how to get this done. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Your `#footerbot img{ ... }` has a `padding-top: 35px;` and a `top: 50%;`, those are pushing the icons away from the top so that is why they are so low. I would recommend removing those.

Comment: @Jeremy I removed top: 50% but i Can't remove padding-top because thats my way to center these icons in footer

Comment: U can also do `#footerbot a{ line-height: 100px; }` `#footerbot img{ height: 60px; margin-top: 20px; }` and remove the `padding-top` as I think this will make sure its absolutely centered the same as your `h5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 uses [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to position the columns in their rows so you can add the following to your CSS to the control the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) of the columns:

```
.col-md-6:last-child {
  order: -1;
}
```

Comment: I added this to media query and its working! Thank u pal! Now i have to center them..

Comment: @MarkR No problem.

Comment: There's no reason to add more CSS. Bootstrap [includes ordering classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#order).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what you provided is the full code sample of your footer or not, but if that's your full html, you're missing a closing  tag.

Also, assuming all you want are the icons to go above the copyright line and centered, try this:

```css
#footerbot .socialIcons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="footerbot">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="socialIcons">
                                <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"  href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"  href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/dribble.png" href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/gplus.png" href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/youtube.png" href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <h5 class="fbh">&copy;2018 - Appo, All Right Reserved</h5>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- end of row -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: text-align to .socialIcons is not working, I tried it already and double-checked now. and yea, it didint copy closing tags ;)